# Regular expressions with non-english unicode phrases using re.compile

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-2.x

I want to return true or false, by asking whether a string includes unicode characters (in short sequences like phrases).

```
words = ['你好朋友','我吃饭'] # equivalent to 'hello friend', 'I had lunch'
uwords = []
for word in words:
    uwords.append(unicode(word,'utf8'))

uwords # [u'\u4f60\u597d\u670b\u53cb', u'\u6211\u5403\u996d']

import re
string = '他吃饭，不是我' # 'she had lunch', 'i did not'
usample = unicode(string, 'utf-8')
pattern = re.compile(u'[\b\u4f60\u597d\u670b\u53cb\b | \b\u6211\u5403\u996d\b]')
# pattern = re.compile(u'\u793e\u533a.*\u670d\u52a1') # [u'\u793e\u533a', u'\u670d\u52a1']
match = pattern.search(usample)

if match:
    print True
else:
    False
```

I have to get False from this code but I got True. I think there is something wrong with the re.compile I wrote, it seems that the code is catching unicode characters separately rather than in sequence.

I think this would be the same for the case in english:

```
import re
string = 'rotten tomatoes are good'
pattern = re.compile('tomatoes are good | apples are good')
match = pattern.search(string)

if match:
    print True
else:
    False
```

This one returned false while I want true.

Comment: Don’t put spaces around `|`.

Comment: The problem here is that you're using `[...]` in your pattern, which means "any of these characters"

Comment: @georg I think that solved the answer

Comment: all characters are unicode characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[abc]` syntax means "match one of `a` or `b` or `c`.  Also `\b` doesn't really work the same with Chinese so removing that is OK as well.

Note if you use Unicode strings the code is much shorter and more readable.

The `#coding` statement declares the encoding of the source file, so the Unicode strings are translated properly.  Make sure to save the source in the declared encoding.

```
#coding:utf8
import re

uwords = [u'你好朋友',u'我吃饭'] # equivalent to 'hello friend', 'I had lunch'

usample = u'他吃饭，不是我' # 'she had lunch', 'i did not'
usample2 = u'你好朋友， 你吃了吗？'

pattern = re.compile(u'你好朋友|我吃饭')

print bool(pattern.search(usample))
print bool(pattern.search(usample2))
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Comment: Can I ask what bool is doing?

Comment: @song0089 Forcing print of True or False instead of a match object or None.

Answer (score 0):

Removing spaces and brackets solved the answer:

```
words = ['你好朋友','我吃饭'] # equivalent to 'hello friend', 'I had lunch'
uwords = []
for word in words:
    uwords.append(unicode(word,'utf8'))

uwords # [u'\u4f60\u597d\u670b\u53cb', u'\u6211\u5403\u996d']

import re
string = '他吃饭，不是我' # 'she had lunch', 'i did not'
usample = unicode(string, 'utf-8')
pattern = re.compile(u'\u4f60\u597d\u670b\u53cb|\u6211\u5403\u996d')
match = pattern.search(usample)

if match:
    print True
else:
    False
```

Comment: I would assume you know Chinese. In this case, you can have a look into http://blog.csdn.net/gatieme/article/details/43235791, which I think is pretty useful.

Comment: The sample program in that link gives bad advice.  Better advice is use the latest Python (3.6).